# Entity Framework and One to Many Relationships not saving right

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I worked with Entity Framework several years ago, and this may just be me being a bit rusty.  I have detached entities, that in turn have multiple child entities.  In my case it's a person entity and each person has multiple addresses.

```
myPerson.FirstName="update first name";
//assuming they already have an address in the first entry 
//with appropriate primary keys and foreign key ids, I could do:
myPerson.Addresses.First().Line1="update line 1";
myPerson.Addresses.Add(new Address(){line1="weee",line2="aaaa" postal="12345", type="work"});
myDb.Person.Attach(myPerson);
myDb.Entry(myPerson).State=EntityState.Modified;
myDb.SaveChanges();
```

When I do a scenario like this, I get what I expect with first name.  It updates the first name, and as expected actually blanks out all other fields (LastName, Birthday etc etc) in the above code.  It doesn't however create the new address for the person, nor does it update the existing address.

I don't recall it requiring extra work for the database context to know how to update the related entities associated with the person above.  In my google searches I seem to be hearing the story that I need to do a considerable amount of work loading collections from the db and then going to town that way.  I hope that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the code you pasted are these lines...

```
myDb.Person.Attach(myPerson);
myDb.Entry(myPerson).State=EntityState.Modified;
```

The first line will attach the entire object graph to the context and set the state of each entity in this graph to Unchanged.  The second line of code will set the state of just the root entity to Modified (the others, such as the Address entities, will remain in the Unchanged state).  When the changes are saved, only the single entity will be updated.

Of course, this assumes that you are working with disconnected entities (using one context to fetch the object graph and another to perform the update).  I assume you are as you are attaching the entity.

/* Rant On */

Disconnected entities is sadly something isn't handled very well in the EF space.  You will find plenty of samples in books and blogs that attempt to address disconnected entities but these strategies quickly fall apart as you try to implement more advanced scenarios (such as object graphs including collections of related items).

/* Rant Off */

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment.  I looked back at the last time I was doing EF, and I realized that I was in a very different scenario.  In that older scenario, I was doing EF against a local sqlite file as the datastore for a WPF app.  So I was in a state-rich environment on a local file and I pretty much was always working with connected entities rather than detached ones.

Comment: In my current scenario, I am working on creating something that lets our business logic developers write against an interface that keeps the specifics of entity framework separate from the business logic code.  Our older applications were written (by my predecessors) with no abstraction of a different ORM as it was used in the business code, and as such we are totally stuck with a different (and very nasty ORM) in those apps.  I don't want to make that mistake again, even though I doubt we will ever want to change from EF.  Too bad it has to be tricky for detached entities.  Thanks.